# How do I add a custom class to a field based on another field value(boolean)?

Tags: theming, entities

I have a Commerce product and there are two price fields. (Original price and Sale price). I would like to display original price as line-through text when sale price is available. Therefore I would like to add a custom class to a field based on another field value(boolean), I looked at this function, hook_entity_view_alter, but I don't know whether it will be good.

Anyone has idea how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used the commerce module but that sounds possible, you need to create a module for the hook to be triggered from.

Then, with the `devel` module installed use `dpm($build, $type)` within the hook to see the correct names (I've put in dummy values in CAPS) and do something like:

```
function MYMODULE_entity_view_alter(&$build, $type){
  if ($type =='product') {
    if (isset($build['SALE_PRICE']['VALUE'])) {
                $build['PRICE']['attributes']['class'] = array('on-sale');
            }
        }
    }
```